# Chaining groupby and apply pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I'm looking for a way to chain groupby and apply, like this (cf code below for a concrete example):

```
df.groupby("a").apply(func_1).groupby("b").apply(func_2)
```

I guess it doesn't work because groupby needs to take in input a dataframe, which is not always the case of the 2nd groupby above (could take in input a serie, cf example). 
A solution could be to have the first apply which outputs the result of func_1 plus the original dataframe, but I haven't found how to do this.

I'm looking for a general workaround, not just a workaround for this specific example.

Example: Let's say that I want to compute the area under curb of a for each group in b and then compute the sum of these areas for each group in c.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":np.arange(8),"b":np.repeat(np.arange(4),2),
"c":np.repeat(np.arange(2),4)})

df
   a  b  c
0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  2  1  0
3  3  1  0
4  4  2  1
5  5  2  1
6  6  3  1
7  7  3  1


df.groupby("b").apply(lambda x: trapz(x["a"])).groupby("c").apply(sum)   
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
KeyError: 'c'


#Expected output
c
0     3.0
1    11.0


#I know that this code works, but I would like to avoid to modify 
#my dataframe :

df["result"]=list(df
    .groupby("b").apply(lambda x: trapz(x["a"]))
    .repeat(df.groupby("b").size()))
df.groupby("b").first().groupby("c").result.sum()
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve with the `lambda x: np.cumsum(x["a"])` function?  Or show the output you are expecting.

Comment: When you present broken code, we don't know what part was intended and what part was a mistake.  Can you show us the numbers you expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I would do something like:

```
# your_fun is the function you want to apply
df.groupby('c').apply(lambda f: sum(f.groupby('b')['a'].apply(your_fun))
```